# Changing minvalue of Postgres's sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I am trying to change minimum value of an existing sequence.

First I tried

```
ALTER SEQUENCE product_id_seq MINVALUE 10000;
```

and I got `ERROR: START value (1) cannot be less than MINVALUE (10000)`.

So I tried

```
ALTER SEQUENCE product_id_seq MINVALUE 10000 RESTART WITH 10000;
```

but got the same error.

Of course I could just drop it and create a new one, but I think there should be a way to do this. I am using Postgres 8.4.7.

Answer (score 16):

How about setting [them all](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) at once:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE product_id_seq
MINVALUE 10000
START 10000
RESTART 10000;
```

That should change the minimum, starting, and current values all to 10000 and thus make everything consistent.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I missed that parameter. =)

Comment: @dasony: Possibly the odd naming of `RESTART` caused some confusion, I would have expected it to be called `CURRENT`.

Answer (score 1):

I Have done the following test, My version is 9.0.

```
--create sequence
skytf=> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test
skytf->     START WITH 1
skytf->     INCREMENT BY 1
skytf->     NO MINVALUE
skytf->     NO MAXVALUE
skytf->     CACHE 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE

skytf=> \d seq_test
           Sequence "skytf.seq_test"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value        
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | seq_test
 last_value    | bigint  | 1
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 1
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | f


skytf=> select nextval('seq_test');
 nextval 
---------
       1
(1 row)

--alter sequence 
skytf=> alter sequence seq_test  restart with 100;
ALTER SEQUENCE
skytf=> \d seq_test
           Sequence "skytf.seq_test"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value        
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | seq_test
 last_value    | bigint  | 100
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 1
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | f

skytf=> select nextval('seq_test');
 nextval 
---------
     100
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has several [functions that operate on sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html). In addition to the other guidance here, you could use

```
SELECT setval('product_id_seq ', 10000); -- Next nextval() returns 10001
```

Comment: Years later, this saved me.