# PostgreSQL: Can a SERIAL start at 0?

Tags: postgresql

In PostGreSQL, can the SERIAL type start at 0?

[This documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) states the range of the SERIAL type starts at 1.

Does this mean it's impossible ?

This question is *not* a duplicate. The other question is about **Prisma** and *not* discoverable for someone looking for an answer about PostGreSQL specifically

Comment: This has been answered as an answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75679539/10469162

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010838/reset-postgres-auto-increment-value-to-0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561244/changing-minvalue-of-postgress-sequence and more

Comment: If the document already tells you the answer, why ask the question ?

Comment: @RohitGupta Maybe the question is poorly worded then but has merit : 
If you saw the answer I linked to in the comment you could have read:
"Although serial occupies the place of data type in the ddl it is not a data type; it is actually a short for..." . Maybe a better question would be : "Is there an alternative to SERIAL that can start at 0" ?